# app getting crashed after adding onclick to the buttons

Tags: java, android, kotlin

i am a new app developer i was working on a app for the past few days i have implemented onclicklistner in my program then the app gets crash itself after adding onclick button in my program and the program excuetes without errors but its getting crashed while running the app and i am using new version of andriod.
thank you

this is my Main activity:

```
package com.example.project5;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 private static int SPLASH_SCREEN = 3000;



 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Dashboard.class);
           startActivity(intent);
           finish();
       }
   },SPLASH_SCREEN);
 }
}
```

this is my Dashboard.java:

```
package com.example.project5;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity {

  Button callSignup;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        callSignup = findViewById(R.id.Signup);

        callSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
              Intent intent = new Intent(Dashboard.this,SignUp.class);

            }

        });


   }
}
```

this is my SignUp.java:

```
package com.example.project5;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
  }
}
```

This is my activity_sign_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp"
    tools:context=".SignUp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:padding="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/bungee"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:textColor="#FF000000"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SignUp To Contiune"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#FF000000"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Full Name"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Username"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:counterMaxLength="15"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Email"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/phonenumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Phone No"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"/>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                app:passwordToggleTint="@color/black"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:textColorHint="#FF000000"
                app:boxStrokeColor="#FF000000"
                app:hintTextColor="@color/black"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="GO"
        android:id="@+id/Signup"
        android:background="#000"
        android:textColor="#fff"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Already have an account ? LogIn"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:textColor="#0000"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

when i attempt to run the emulator the app is getting crashed it ends after splash screen

This is my Logcat:

```
2022-10-20 22:12:15.729 14200-14200/com.example.project5 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.project5, PID: 14200
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.project5/com.example.project5.Dashboard}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3740)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3898)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2305)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:257)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8192)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:626)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1015)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.project5.Dashboard.onCreate(Dashboard.java:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8119)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8103)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1359)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3713)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3898) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2305) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:257) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8192) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:626) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1015) 
2022-10-20 22:12:15.799 14200-14200/com.example.project5 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14200 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for an element with ID `Signup` but the view tree you are searching through is the one in defined by your `activity_dashboard` XML file as that is what the content is set to by `Dashboard` make sure you are both setting the right content and that the ID you are looking for is used on an element in the view set as the content.

Comment: can u explain me clearly if u dont mind..

Comment: Is there an element defined in `activity_dashboard` with an ID of `Signup`? The issue is you are trying to set an `OnClickListener` for a view element that does not exist (hence the null pointer exception you see in logcat). `Dashboard` sets the content via `setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard)` if your `activity_dashboard` layout doesn't include an element with ID `Signup` `findViewById` will give null because no view with that ID can be found. You need to make sure that you are both setting the correct layout and getting the right button.